# The map in hector_slam blinks

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hokuyo, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use a laser Hokuyo UTM-30LX with hector-slam in ROS hydro.
I create a .bag used **rosbag record -O name -a**  When run hokuyo_node and hector_slam.
The problem is that when I play this .bag in hector_slam, the map created by hector_mapping in rviz blinks, the LaserScan and the Path are ok. And when the reproduction goes to the end, the map disappears.
Someone knows why is this?
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
If I play my file .bag when I used `rosrun rviz rviz`. The map is OK but is not ok when I executed hector_slam.
I want execute hector_slam and play my file .bag because I search rebuild a map and follow scan the room.
This is the launch file that I use for launch hector_slam:

```
 <launch>
 
 <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>ros
 
 <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
 args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.rviz"/>
 
 <include file="$(find slam_launch)/launch/hector_mapping.launch"/>
 
 <include file="$(find slam_launch)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
 <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/> 
 </include>
 
 </launch>
```

This is the hector_mapping:

```
 <launch>
 
 <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping"    output="screen">
 
 <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
 <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
 <param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
 <param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
 <param name="map_resolution" value="0.025"/>

 <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
 <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
 <param name="laser_z_min_value" value="-2.5" />
 <param name="laser_z_max_value" value="7.5" />
 
  <param name="laser_max_dist" value="10" />
  <param name="map_size" value="5000"/>
  <param name="map_pub_period" value="1.0"/>
  <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>

 
 <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
 <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
 <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
 <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
 </node>
 
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster"      args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100" />  
 
 </launch>
```

I can´t put links with my .bag but this is the output of `rosbag info probatopics-7.bag` :

```
path:        probatopics-7.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    13.2s
start:       Jan 30 2014 14:56:21.36 (1391090181.36)
end:         Jan 30 2014 14:56:34.54 (1391090194.54)
size:        317.4 MB
messages:    3236
compression: none [14/14 chunks]
types:       diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray         [3cfbeff055e708a24c3d946a5c8139cd]
             dynamic_reconfigure/Config              [958f16a05573709014982821e6822580]
             dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription   [757ce9d44ba8ddd801bb30bc456f946f]
             geometry_msgs/PoseStamped               [d3812c3cbc69362b77dc0b19b345f8f5]
             geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped [953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246]
             nav_msgs/MapMetaData                    [10cfc8a2818024d3248802c00c95f11b]
             nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid                  [3381f2d731d4076ec5c71b0759edbe4e]
             nav_msgs/Path                           [6227e2b7e9cce15051f669a5e197bbf7]
             rosgraph_msgs/Log                       [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan                   [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
             sensor_msgs/PointCloud                  [d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca]
             tf2_msgs/TFMessage                      [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
topics:      /diagnostics                            13 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray        
             /hokuyo_node/parameter_descriptions      1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription  
             /hokuyo_node/parameter_updates           1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/Config             
             /map                                    13 msgs    : nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid                 
             /map_metadata                            1 msg     : nav_msgs/MapMetaData                   
             /poseupdate                            483 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped
             /rosout                                 37 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log                       (6 connections)
             /rosout_agg                             25 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log                      
             /scan                                  522 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan                  
             /slam_cloud                            486 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud                 
             /slam_out_pose                         481 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseStamped              
             /tf                                   1169 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage                      (2 connections)
             /trajectory                              4 msgs    : nav_msgs/Path
```

EDIT2:
This photo is when I make my field .bag:
[image: image description]
And this is when I execute my .bag and I run hector_slam:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124521/the-map-in-hector_slam-blinks./) by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-30**:
Did you run SLAM while recording the bag file and run it again while playing the bag file?

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-01-30**:
No, I only run SLAM while recording the bag file. When I playing the bag file I turn off the hokuyo_node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably happening because in your bag you have a map or transformations that are also being created by the nodes you are running to post-process the bag file. So, for example, you can have a map being published from your bag and a map being published from hector_slam.

You may try to create a bag file only with the laser topic:

```
rosbag record -O name /scan
```

In resume: take a look at [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping), it only subscribes to `/scan` and `/syscommand` (this is only used to send a reset command, so you can disregard it). So if you want to create a bag file to use with your hector_slam launch file, it only requires  information of the `/scan` topic.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-01-30**:
I think that you be right.
And How I could edit my file for run hector_slam and play my file .bag?
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-01-30**:
If I create a .bag used /scan and /tf. When I reproduce this .bag in hector_slam I saw the laser scan. The problem is the map, if i use /scan /tf /map and /map_metadata, When I reproduce the .bag, the map blinks in the screen. No blinks if I execute rosrun rviz rviz, but I don´t want this.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-02-01**:
try to record only /scan and them publish the static transformations that you have (e.g. from base to laser sensor) while playing the bag file and launching your hector launch file.

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-02-10**:
Sorry for the delay.
If I understand well, I recorded only /scan and after I played this .bag while hector  was running.
The /tf is in EDIT:3

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-02-10**:
but does that solved your problem? I will edit your question because there is some info there that is not useful.

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-02-10**:
No, only with the /scan or with /scan and /tf, I can´t create a map. For create a map, I need /map and /tf. You can create a map only with /scan?
Thanks for edit.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-02-10**:
yes, that is what hector_slam does.

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-02-11**:
Umm.. I can create a map with /scan online, but no with  /scan in file.bag